# How do i remove anything inside parentheses () in python

Tags: python, regex

How do I remove whatever is inside the brackets?

Sample string:

```
cost
889990(+2.4%)
```

My code:

```
data['cost']=re.sub(('(\d+)'), '', data.cost)
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
cost
889990
```

Comment: Does the code you've shown not work? Why not? Is “result” what you want or what you actually get?

Comment: It's not clear what you want in the final result. Removing everything inside the brackets gives:  `cost 889990()` is that what you're trying to get?

Comment: What type of object is `data`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the parentheses in your regex string:

```
import re

s = 'cost 889990(+2.4%)'

print(re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', s))
```

Prints:

```
cost 889990
```